# Java Applet to Download files files

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have an applet that is executed in an HTML file that the user downloads and opens locally (i.e. `file://` on the URL bar). This applet has a method that downloads a file from the web and stores it in a directory inside the directory where the applet is running. On my HTML file I call the function to download a file and it works but when I call it the second time, to download another file, I get a `Error calling method on NPObject.` I don't get any error on the Java side (I have the console open and it stays clean).
What can be the issue here? Thank you a lot for your help. Below, the code of the applet.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EPPenDrive extends java.applet.Applet {

    public final static String baseURL = "http://localhost/data/documents/";

    public String downloadFile(final String filename) {
        return (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {       
              try {
                URL finalURL = new URL(baseURL + filename);
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(finalURL.openStream());
                URL appletDir = getCodeBase();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(appletDir.getPath() + "documents/"+ filename);
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                return 1;
              } catch (Exception x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
                return null;
              }
            }
          });
    }

    public void init() { }
    public void stop() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the `run()` method would block if returning 1. I changed it to `return null` and now everything works. :)